# groovy - problem parsing xml

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I am new to Groovy and I am trying to parse both a valid rest resource and an invalid one.
For example:

this code works fine -

```
def entity = new XmlSlurper().parse('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/slashdot.xml')
println entity.name()
println entity.screen_name.text()
```

---

### when I run it, I get output:

```
user
slashdot
```

---

### but when I pass an invalid url to xmlSlurper, like this

```
def entity = new XmlSlurper().parse('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/slashdotabc.xml')
println entity.name()
println entity.screen_name.text(
```

### )

I get this error message:

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/slashdotabc.xml
    at xmltest.run(xmltest.groovy:1)
```

---

Although the url returns an hash code (like below) with an error message which I would like to parse and display it.

```
<hash>
<request>/1/users/show/slashdotabc.xml</request>
<error>Not found</error>
</hash>
```

How can I parse a url which returns a 404 but with error information?

Any help will be appreciated.

-- 
Thanks & Regards,
Frank Covert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response you want to see is available on the URL connection's `errorStream` instead of the `inputStream`.  Fortunately, given the `InputStream`, `XmlSlurper.parse` can read an `InputStream` as well.

Here's a sample to switch to reading the `errorStream` when you don't get a 200 status:

```
def con = new URL("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/slashdotaxxxbc.xml").openConnection()
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(con.responseCode == 200 ? con.inputStream : con.errorStream)
```

Comment: thanks, that works. Do I need to close the con in the end? like con.Close() or something like that?